# Custom validators don't change my ngClass

Tags: angular, forms

my console.log work exactly like I want, but the error is printed in all cases. I can see that cause my ngclass show me only the error mode.

My form :

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
 pseudo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
 birthDate: ['', [Validators.required, majorValidator()]],
 email: ['', [Validators.required]],
 password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
});
```

My custom validators :

```
export function majorValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    if (control.value !== '') {
      const diff = (Date.now().valueOf() - control.value) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 365;
      if (diff > 18) {
        console.log('ok');
        return {'ageValid': {value: control.value}};
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

And this it's in my view :

```
<div class="birthDate-response row mx-auto">
   <span class="mx-auto no-valid " *ngIf="f.birthDate.ageValid""> Vous devez avoir 18 ans au minimum </span>
</div>
```

If you can find the solution thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a closer look at angular docs. Your unerstanding of validation function is not 100% correct:

```
It takes an Angular control object as an argument and returns either null if the form is valid, or ValidationErrors otherwise.
```

So, basically, you forgot to return `null` in cases when value is valid.

you need min 18 years old? maybe then you need to inverse your conition:

```
if (control.value !== '') {
      const diff = (Date.now().valueOf() - control.value) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 365;
      if (diff > 18) {
        console.log('ok');
        return null;
      } else {
        return {'ageValid': {value: control.value}};
      }
    }
    return null;
```

also, this is a bit strange: `Date.now().valueOf()` - your user will input his age in ticks? :)

Comment: thank you I did an update with the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation. But my error it's not printed :/